# How to randomize a string array when a button is pressed?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have an array of strings and I would like to display 1 of the random values from the string array when the button is pressed. So when the "Vowels" button is pressed it displays 1 of the random vowels in the textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method on the `Button.Click` event:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim rnd As New Random

    Private Sub Button1_Click (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = strVowels(rnd.Next(strVowels.Length))
    End Sub
End Class
```

(Thanks for the reminder of the limits of `Random`,  @StevenDoggart!)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `Random` object's randomization algorithm is seeded with the current time in its constructor, so, if you plan to call `Next` multiple times, it's best to only create the `Random` object once, such as in the `Form.Load` and reuse the same object each time.

Comment: @Viktor Ek I get an error with that code that says "Expression is not a method" ?

Comment: @Hassan I updated my code so you can easier see how to implement the example!